# How do i get value from Select input using jQuery after DOM has been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a value of a `select` but it keeps returning `undefined`. I have looked in a lot of places but can't seem to find the solution. I know it's to do with DOM being loaded before and not seeing my `select`. The thing is, I do get to a point where it says `undefined` after I change a value of `select`.

```
var getMethod = function(select) {
    var method = select;
    var d = $(method).val();
    return d;
}

$(document).on("change", "#select-main", function() {
    $("#container").replaceWith("<div class='containter text-center'><h1>Loading...</h1><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x'></i></div><br>");
    $("#container-table").remove();
    $("#header").remove();
    $("#export-button").remove();

    var newSelect = getMethod("#select-main");
    var newData = getDataToSend(links, newSelect);
    mainFunc(newSelect, newData);
});
```

The above code produces undefined when using `.val()`, as it does not see that there is a new input, but when I call `.on()` event on the `input`, I can do things like `alert("HERE!");`

Any advice?

Comment: btw I create a new input like this in ajax call
`$("div.main_holder").append("<div class='container' id='container'><div class='row'><select class='form-control' id='select-main'><option>Social Values</option><option>Social Visibility</option><option>Organic Keyword Count</option><option>Seo Visibility</option></select></div></div>");`

Comment: why dont just "return $(select).val();" but anyway post your html

Comment: @AndrejsGubars Edit your original post rather than posting additional information in a comment.

Comment: thats a point! well the html is created in ajax success call as posted above.
The point of this question is to get an understanding of how to retrieve values after new elements been dynamically created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is the value of the text between the options tag you shoud use text(); that is

```
$(method).text()
```

val is for the value of the value attribute in the select so

```
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="5">Prof</option>
</select>
```

`$('#myselect').val()` is 5
`$('#myselect').text()` is Prof

I would try this

```
 $(document).on("change", "#select-main", function() {



var valueYouAreLookingFor = $(this.selectedOptions).text();

console.log(valueYouAreLookingFor);


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sudakatux/fLy3hpem/

Hope it helps

Comment: Spot on! it works perfectly now, can you explain please this line
`var valueYouAreLookingFor = $(this.selectedOptions).text();` just so I get a deeper understanding

Comment: Sure. the word ```this```, is for the select itself. the selectedOptions returns an array of selected options, with one element in the select, wrapping the element (the selected option) in the jquery selector, lets me use jquery functions, so i can retrieve its value or text

Comment: Okay, thank you! It just confused me that I could get a value by calling `return $(select).val();` on the elements that have been created and has been put in DOM, but when I dynamically create new ones, I can not use the same method to get that value.